# How to add a function only to woocommerce pages

Tags: javascript, wordpress, woocommerce, breadcrumbs

I have this code I put in to remove part of my breadcrumbs in woocommerce which said "Products" in the second crumb:

```
if( $item_position === 2 ){continue;}
```

While it does work, it also removes the second breadcrumb from my other pages, while I just want it to remove it from woocommerce so I tried:

```
if ( is_woocommerce && $item_position === 2 ){continue;}
```

Which did the same as the previous, and I also tried:

```
if (is_woocommerce ($item_position === 2 ){continue;}
```

Which now works on my other pages but will completely remove breadcrumbs from woocommerce.
I'm just learning and I have no idea what i'm doing wrong.

Comment: the syntax is obviously incorrect. `is_woocommerce()` is a function and this is not JavaScript, it's PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`is_woocommerce()` is a function.

The correct syntax is:

```
if (is_woocommerce() && $item_position === 2 ) { 
    continue; 
}
```